# Exception when casting IOleDropTarget pDataObj object - Invalid FORMATETC structure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040064 (DV_E_FORMATETC)

Tags: vb.net, winapi, outlook, drag-and-drop

I have implemented the IOleDropTarget interface and am also using the IDropTargetHelper interface to show the system icon of the file being dragged.

Part of my DragEnter code looks like this

```
Public Function OleDragEnter(<[In]> <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)> pDataObj As Object, <[In]> <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)> grfKeyState As Integer, <[In]> <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U8)> pt As Long, <[In]> <Out> ByRef pdwEffect As Integer) As Integer Implements IOleDropTarget.OleDragEnter

    Dim x As Integer = CInt(pt And &H7FFFFFFF)
    Dim y As Integer = CInt((pt >> 32) And &H7FFFFFFF)
    Dim winPT As Win32Point
    winPT.x = CInt(pt And &H7FFFFFFF)
    winPT.y = CInt((pt >> 32) And &H7FFFFFFF)

    ddHelper.DragEnter(hwnd, CType(pDataObj, NativeMethods.IDataObject), winPT, 0)
End Function
```

The cast of the pDataObj to an IDataObject works for every kind of object I can drag except for an Outlook email attachment.  An email itself works fine but not an attachment. The error is Invalid FORMATETC structure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040064 (DV_E_FORMATETC)

Where do I start to work out what I am doing wrong? What code should I show?

my IDataObject interface looks like this

```
 <ComImport, Guid("0000010E-0000-0000-C000-000000000046"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)>
    Interface IDataObject
        <PreserveSig>
        Function GetData(
<[In]> ByRef format As FORMATETC, <Out> ByRef medium As STGMEDIUM) As Integer
        <PreserveSig>
        Function GetDataHere(
<[In]> ByRef format As FORMATETC, ByRef medium As STGMEDIUM) As Integer
        <PreserveSig>
        Function QueryGetData(
<[In]> ByRef format As FORMATETC) As Integer
        <PreserveSig>
        Function GetCanonicalFormatEtc(
<[In]> ByRef formatIn As FORMATETC, <Out> ByRef formatOut As FORMATETC) As Integer
        <PreserveSig>
        Function SetData(
<[In]> ByRef formatIn As FORMATETC,
<[In]> ByRef medium As STGMEDIUM,
<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> ByVal release As Boolean) As Integer
        <PreserveSig>
        Function EnumFormatEtc(ByVal direction As ComTypes.DATADIR, <Out> ByRef ppenumFormatEtc As System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IEnumFORMATETC) As Integer
        <PreserveSig>
        Function DAdvise(
<[In]> ByRef pFormatetc As FORMATETC, ByVal advf As ComTypes.ADVF, ByVal adviseSink As ComTypes.IAdviseSink, <Out> ByRef connection As Integer) As Integer
        <PreserveSig>
        Function DUnadvise(ByVal connection As Integer) As Integer
        <PreserveSig>
        Function EnumDAdvise(<Out> ByRef enumAdvise As ComTypes.IEnumSTATDATA) As Integer
    End Interface
```

and FORMATETC structure like this

```
 <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
    Public NotInheritable Class FORMATETC
        Public cfFormat As UShort
        Public dummy As Short
        Public ptd As IntPtr
        Public dwAspect As Integer
        Public lindex As Integer
        Public tymed As Integer
    End Class
```

**UPDATED**
ddHelper is an instance of my class cast from the IDropTargetHelper interface.

```
Private ddHelper As IDropTargetHelper = CType(New DragDropHelper(), IDropTargetHelper)
```

class and interface look like this

```
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
Public Structure Win32Point
    Public x As Integer
    Public y As Integer
End Structure

<ComImport>
<Guid("4657278A-411B-11d2-839A-00C04FD918D0")>
Public Class DragDropHelper
End Class

<ComVisible(True)>
<ComImport>
<Guid("4657278B-411B-11D2-839A-00C04FD918D0")>
<InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)>
Interface IDropTargetHelper
    Sub DragEnter(
<[In]> ByVal hwndTarget As IntPtr,
<[In], MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.[Interface])> ByVal dataObject As NativeMethods.IDataObject,
<[In]> ByRef pt As Win32Point,
<[In]> ByVal effect As Integer)
    Sub DragLeave()
    Sub DragOver(
<[In]> ByRef pt As Win32Point,
<[In]> ByVal effect As Integer)
    Sub Drop(
<[In], MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.[Interface])> ByVal dataObject As NativeMethods.IDataObject,
<[In]> ByRef pt As Win32Point,
<[In]> ByVal effect As Integer)
    Sub Show(
<[In]> ByVal show As Boolean)
End Interface
```

And the error looks like this. 
[image]

Comment: Where are you getting the error from? What is `ddHelper`?

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: Obviously, the `IDataObject` provided by the drag source does not contain any formats that your `DragDropHandler` accepts. You can use `IDataObject.EnumFormatEtc()` to discover the available formats. Or, just catch the error and move on, returning an appropriate error code to the source (your `OleDragEnter()` is not returning any value to the caller, you need to fix that).

Comment: if by formats you mean cfFormat from Formatetc then I can successfully call OleQueryGetData using both CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTORA or CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTORW. Further if the IDataobject format is incorrect am I on the right track that I can swap this format out for another? OleDragEnter has much more code than this.  I return a S_OK or 0.

Comment: @RemyLebeau for example this https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28209/Outlook-Drag-and-Drop-in-C it appears he wraps the IDataObject to change the format so that Outlook items are understood by other programs.  Is this what I need to do?

Comment: "*if by formats you mean cfFormat from Formatetc*" - I'm not just referring to the `cfFormat`.  The *entire* `FORMATETC` has to be acceptable, as it contains not just WHICH data format is being transferred but also HOW it is being transferred, too (`HGLOBAL`, `IStream`, etc). So, in this case, the source's `FORMATETC` is likely specifying a format+transfer combo that your `DragDropHelper` doesn't support. You may have to handle the offending combo manually in your own code and not let the `DragDropHandler` handle it

Comment: Thanks @RemyLebeau I now have noticed that windows does not even manage to show an icon when dragging Outlook attachments so there must be something really special with the Format Office uses.